# Apache/Django subdomains problem

Tags: django, apache, configuration, subdomain

Now I have apache configuration which works only with localhost domain (http://localhost/).

```
Alias /media/ "/ścieżka/do/instalacji/django/contrib/admin/media/"
Alias /site_media/ "/ścieżka/do/plikow/site_media/"
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
    PythonPath "['/thomas/django_projects/project'] + sys.path"
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
<Location "/site_media">
SetHandler none
</Location>
```

How can I make it working for some subdomains like pl.localhost or uk.localhost?
This subdomains should display the same page what domain (localhost).

Second question: It is possible change default localhost address (http://localhost/) to (http://localhost.com/) or (http://www.localhost.com/) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ServerAlias directive in apache for different hosts

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerAlias pl.localhost
ServerAlias uk.localhost
Alias /media/ "/ścieżka/do/instalacji/django/contrib/admin/media/"
Alias /site_media/ "/ścieżka/do/plikow/site_media/"
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
    PythonPath "['/thomas/django_projects/project'] + sys.path"
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
<Location "/site_media">
SetHandler none
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but if you dont use internet domains with a configured dns you need also to update yor hosts file with the hosts you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks Meska,
I resolved the problem. I added to `/etc/hosts` file something like:

`127.0.0.1        pl.localhost`

`127.0.0.1        uk.localhost`

`127.0.0.1        www.localhost.com`